# AntiForgery.Validate Always Validates Even When no Match

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, antiforgerytoken

I have a class which is used to perform Validation of Antiforgery tokens where the payload is Json. That class looks like this (from Phil Haacked):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(filterContext, null)) throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");

        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        //  Only validate POSTs
        if (request.HttpMethod == WebRequestMethods.Http.Post)
        {
            //  Ajax POSTs and normal form posts have to be treated differently when it comes
            //  to validating the AntiForgeryToken
            if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                var antiForgeryCookie = request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];

                var cookieValue = ReferenceEquals(antiForgeryCookie, null) ? null : antiForgeryCookie.Value;

                AntiForgery.Validate(cookieValue, request.Headers[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName]);
            }
            else
            {
                new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute().OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is the first Angular project I am using it on and it is not throwing an exception where I would expect it to. For example, the value in the header differs from the value in the cookie and the call to `AntiForgery.Validate` proceeds without exception.

The anti-forgery token is rendered in the shell view (i.e. Index.cshtml) and it is added to the headers in Angular's module run function:

```
// Handle routing errors and success events
theApp.run(['$http', '$route', '$rootScope', '$q', 'routeOverlord',
    function ($http, $route, $rootScope, $q, routeOverlord) {
        // Include $route to kick start the router.
        routeOverlord.setRoutingHandlers();

        // Include AntiForgeryToken to prevent CSRF attacks
        $http.defaults.headers.common['__RequestVerificationToken'] = angular.element('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    }]);
```

Is this a known thing? Happy to provide a Fiddler screenshot of the differing strings in the cookie and header if requested.

Cheers

Comment: don't have time to test, but shouldn't this line `AntiForgery.Validate(cookieValue, request.Headers[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName]);` be looking for a header with the name of `__RequestVerificationToken` and not `AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName`

Comment: @SBurris AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName is a static string on that framework class which resolves to __RequestVerificationToken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookie token and the form token (the one in the headers in your case) are **not** supposed to be identical (it would be easier to fake).

The cookie token contains a random blob. The form token contains the same blob, plus some identity data (and optionally some additional data).

`AntiForgery.Validate()` checks that both blobs are identical, and that the other data in the form token corresponds to the identity data and the optional additional data.

Comment: Thanks Philippe. That sounds plausible. Good enough.

Comment: Is there any actual documentation on this behaviour? How or where did you discover this?

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk I don't know if there is any documentation for this. I found it from .NET code with Reflector (specifically AntiForgeryWorker.GetAntiForgeryAndSetCookie() and .Validate() methods).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this as well.  The cookie value and the field value being different but the .Net framework still letting them through.

This is because the .Net Framework's implementation is a little more complicated then a simple value matching check.

After looking over the source code on Github, see that the tokens contain additional information besides just a GUID (they are tying it to the current user).

I can see form the TokenValidator that the cookie value is a token representing a SessionToken where the field value (your header value) is not expected to be a session token.

```
// Do the tokens have the correct format?
if (!sessionToken.IsSessionToken || fieldToken.IsSessionToken)
{
    throw HttpAntiForgeryException.CreateTokensSwappedException(_config.CookieName, _config.FormFieldName);
}
```

But the pair of them are still used to verify the action did come from the authorized user and not some precanned attack from a malicious person.

I personally need to do more studying of Microsoft's implementation, but from the little bit I see right now (and linked below) the values should most certainly be different.

References I looked at:

- [AntiXsrf AntiForgery](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiForgery.cs)
- [AntiXsrf AntiForgeryWorker](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiXsrf/AntiForgeryWorker.cs)
- [AntiXsrf TokenValidator](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiXsrf/TokenValidator.cs)
- [AntiXsrf AntiForgeryTokenSerializer](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiXsrf/AntiForgeryTokenSerializer.cs)